# Is it possible to call a child's constructor inside the parent?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

My actual setup is a bit complicated, so I'll formulate a more generic example.  Consider the following classes (using Java syntax):

```
class Set
{
...
    Set subSet(Element[] elementList)
    {
    ...
    }
}

class SetOfNumbers extends Set
{
...
    int operationOnSetsOfNumbers()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to write the following code:

```
Set someSet = new SetOfNumbers(...);
System.out.println(someSet.subset(...).operationOnSetsOfNumbers());
```

Of course, this won't compile because operationOnSetsOfNumbers() is not a member of Set.  One solution is to just implement the subSet method for each child class separately, giving it the appropriate return type each time, but this is obviously inelegant if the implementation of subSet is complicated and there are lots of children.  I would like a way to somehow refer to an arbitrary child of Set inside Set's member functions, but I can't think of a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just take advantage of polymorphism and cast the return value from subset to the correct type?

Comment: Hmm... I suppose in this example you can.  In my actual code this was throwing exceptions, but there were other complications that I tried to sidestep in my question.  I'll investigate.

Comment: I suppose the simple answer is to make operationOnSetsOfNumbers abstract in the base class and implement it in each derived class. Java allows you to have a more specific return type in the implementing methods if that's what you requires. Can I caution you against doing too much in a constructor. Calling out to other methods (particularly non-final methods in the same class) just leads to a world of pain. May be you could consider using a factory method instead of a constructor?

Comment: if subSet() is creating a new Set object, then that Set can't be downcasted to SetOfNumbers.  I assume this is why you got exceptions when you tried casting.  What exactly is subSet doing?  Does it always return only a Set, or does it return a subclass?

Comment: @Joe: For every child T of Set, I want T to have a member function subSet which returns an object of type T.  One way to do this is to implement that function separately for every subclass, but the code is basically the same every single time, except for the return type (indeed, it only uses members of Set).  So it feels like one should only have to implement the member function once, at the level of Set.

Comment: @Stormcloud: the point of the operationOnSetsOfNumbers is that I don't necessarily want every child of Set to have it.  For instance, "SetOfNumbers" might have a member function "sum()", but this wouldn't make sense for "SetOfStrings".  Also, the issue here isn't that I want to do something complicated in a constructor, it's that I want to call a constructor where I can't.  I wish there were a reserved word "child" which refers to the type of a child class, so that my syntax for the subset function would be "child subset(Element[] elementList)".

Comment: Well, it can't *just* be the return type that's different, but the subclass of Set that's being created would be different also.  What you could do is pass subSet a parameter to tell it which type to create.  The return type of subSet would still be "Set", but within the method it would create a `new SetOfNumbers`, `new SetOfFoo`, etc., based on the parameter.  You would still need to cast the result, as so: `((SetOfNumbers)someSet.subset(...)).operationOnSetsOfNumbers()`

Comment: @Joe: is there a way to pass a type as a parameter?  Or do you suggest that I pass a parameter like "int type" and then in my code write "if(type == 4){x = new SetOfNumbers();} else if..."?  The problem is that I can't really predict the children of Set: in fact in my real code the class which plays the role of Set is abstract and the user is meant to inherit from it to gain access to algorithms in another class.  It would be kind of a pain to update Set every time you want to inherit from it.

Comment: `if(type == 4){x = new SetOfNumbers();} else if...` is the right idea, but you're right - you'd have to update subSet for each potential subclass  How complex is subSet, really?  If you're concerned about repeating a large chunk of code in each subclass, you could put the bulk of the code in Set, then override it in each subclass, with the subclass method calling super(...) and creating the appropriate instance of a Set subclass. The bottom line here is that in order to call operationOnSetsOfNumbers(), you *have* to have an instance of SetOfNumbers; whether it's created in Set or  SetOfNumbers

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from generics as follows:

```
class Set<T extends Set<T>>
{
    ...
    T subSet(Element[] elementList)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class SetOfNumbers extends Set<SetOfNumbers>
{
    ...
    int operationOnSetsOfNumbers()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, when you called `subSet()` method on a `SetOfNumbers` instance, the return type will be `SetOfNumbers` instead of Set. Therefore, you will be able to subsequently call `operationOnSetsOfNumbers` after calling subSet().